# Variable Js not working in PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html

can help me with this code.  I need get position of image and save in variable PHP and then write top and left positions in div html.
I tried all ways but I failed
Thanks

```
<?php

echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'>\n";
echo "</script>\n";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";  

echo "window.onload = function() {\n";  

echo "var position = $('#image').position();\n";    

echo "};\n";

echo "</script>\n"; 

$top =  "<script> document.write(position.top) </script>";
$left = "<script> document.write(position.left) </script>";


echo "<div style='position: absolute; top: ".$top."px; left: ".$left."px; opacity: 1;'>\n";

echo "</div>";
```

?>

Comment: do you know the difference between client side and serverside?

Comment: Why are you echoing javascript for no apparent reason?

Comment: I cant understand why you are doing this way. Why are you using PHP anyway?

Comment: What problem are you having?  What result are you getting and how is that different than your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to move a div to the same position as `#image`, you can accomplish that entirely without PHP.

Something like this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var position = $('#image').position();
    $('div').css('top',position.top + 'px');
    $('div').css('left',position.left + 'px');
})
```

You can see it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/4bk852kv/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Server Side Script are being translated on server before the server pushes the page toward clients. So JavaScript variables are unavailable in this step.

As a suggestion you may modify the code to set the inner html using pure Javascript:

```
<?php

echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'>\n";
echo "</script>\n";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";  
echo "window.onload = function() {\n";  
echo "var position = $('#image').position();\n";    
?>

document.write ("<div style='position: absolute; top: "+position.top+"px; left: "+position.left+"px; opacity: 1;'>"

<?php
echo "};\n";
echo "</script>\n"; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali  . I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If You need DIV element as described You shouldn't use PHP. Also You will need width and heigth for Your DIV same as IMG element have. Here code for this:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        var position = $('#image').position();
        $('#info').css({
            'top': position.top,
            'left': position.left,
            'width': $('#image').width(),
            'height': $('#image').height()
        });
    });
</script>
<img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/800px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png" />
<div id="info" style='position: absolute; opacity: 1;'></div>
```

Do not think You can have position of image on PHP (server) side.